# Plugin block not displayed in views page

Tags: views, 8, theming, plugins

1. I have a created views (page) to display the number of news articles created in each month (This displays month (number of articles) added in that month like May(12)).
2. I created a content page and linked that views.
3. Provided a menu link for that content page.
4. I have a plugin block that displays menu active trail (in sidebar) on a region in that page

Now the sidebar plugin block displayed correctly if I am on the content page. But if I click on any month that takes me to a views page which displays list of articles for that month. But in this page the left sidebar is not showing.

I placed my plugin block in left region and made sure it displays on all content types.

Anything else I need to do to display plugin block in a region if I am on a views page?

Comment: Edit that block and Under pages provide menu link in which you want to display that block. As you have given only in content type, it is displaying only in that content type nodes. So provide menu link under pages also to display it in Month pages.

Comment: Yes, In `pages` I have given `/news/*` , I forgot to mention that in question.

Comment: Thanks @AjayReddy I think I will be need to delete this question. I am not sure why I had 2 "Content Types" section in block configuration. I removed all the restrictions in both `content types` section, and removed all restrictions on `pages`. Now the plugin block is showing correctly.